# Jmeter Tests work at the console, but not with the JMeter Jenkins(Performance) plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, load-testing

I'm working with Maven(3.3.9), JMeter (3.0) and the Jenkis Performance plugin.
When I run my JMeter test with Mvn on my Computer, everything works fine, but when I try to make a build @Jenkins, the JMeter tests always fail(100%).

Has anybody an idea what could be the cause for my problem?

My JMeter tests use an assertion, which checks for "viewExpired", because I'm using JSF, and a second assertion, which skips all the other tests as soon as the first test fails.

Here is my log (i changed it a bit, server-adress,etc.) 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/801ef819233468246eb9e42893366b56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom -

From your logs, it looks to me that your TLS connections are failing from the Jenkins machine to the target test server (test.at.com). If your Jenkins machine has an Xterm interface, can you install JMeter there and launch it in the GUI mode to validate? Your test plan should run without issues. The logs also indicate that it is using an empty key store. Do you have the `test.at.com` certificate added to the default java key store on your Jenkins machine? By default, JMeter uses the java key store present under /lib/security. You can override it with your own trust store by using the property

You can edit the JMeter `system.properties` to use a custom Keystore by editing the below lines

```
\# Keystore properties (client certificates)

\# Location

\#javax.net.ssl.keyStore=H:\\cert\\client_keystore.jks

\#

\#The password to your keystore

\#javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit

\#

\#javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider

\#javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType [default = KeyStore.getDefaultType()]
```

I would also suggest enabling the SSL debug options if you want to know the actual root cause. You can turn it on in the system.properties
`\#javax.net.debug=ssl`

Having said all the above, please can you check if the connectivity is there between your Jenkins machine and the actual target host

```
**telnet test.at.com 443**

2017/01/23 15:50:17 DEBUG - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.JMeterClientConnectionOperator$JMeterDefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:33542<->62.116.177.251:443 closed 
2017/01/23 15:50:17 DEBUG - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$7: Closing the connection. 
2017/01/23 15:50:17 DEBUG - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.JMeterClientConnectionOperator$JMeterDefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:33542<->62.116.177.251:443 closed 
2017/01/23 15:50:17 DEBUG - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.JMeterClientConnectionOperator$JMeterDefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:33542<->62.116.177.251:443 shut down 
2017/01/23 15:50:17 DEBUG - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.JMeterClientConnectionOperator$JMeterDefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:33542<->62.116.177.251:443 closed
```

Comment: the strange thing is that at around 2 of 10 builds, the tests success (sorry I forgot to mention this at the question), so I don't think it's caused by SSL

Comment: Thomas - Were you able to verify if you are able to connect to the target host by using "telnet 62.116.177.251 443". Also, please can you do a "wget https://test.at.com and post the output? I would like to see if it resolves to a single IP or not. Also, do you have the ssl debug trace output? I am asking this since your logs indicate that JMeter is trying to send the request but it is not able to send it and the connection is getting closed. Sorry if my understanding is wrong.